# Use PHP Include offline

Tags: php, include, offline

In testing our site it would be so much easier to use PHP include offline. Essentially rather than put a page together for the purposes of testing, we would rather just include the various html files from their respective areas.

Our macs do not render PHP pages when offline and just show the source code. Is there a way to  make them?

Comment: Install a local web server and add PHP so you can dev ([directions for OS X](http://php.about.com/od/phpbasics/ss/installMac.htm))

Answer (score 0):

You need a local webserver in order to run php in your browser.

check out [mamp](http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html) or [zend server](http://www.zend.com/products/server/)

Once installed you can type `localhost` and whatever is the default directory will show in your browser. What I usually do is instad of just accessing everything through `localhost` I create an alias in the `/private.etc/hosts/` file and the `http.conf` file in mamp

Answer (score 0):

You would need a local web server to render any PHP code. MAMP might help you : www.mamp.info

Answer (score 0):

To include HTML code into php with `include()` or `require()` you'll have to change the extension of the files from `.html` to `.php` even if no PHP code is inside them.

Also you could use a localhost server. There are mainly 2 of them for Mac:

1. Mamp
2. Xampp

I use the latter and I think it's the best. I had some trouble with Mamp years ago while Xampp worked just fine.

Comment: I know that. Read the question. I stated that offline the browser will not read PHP

Comment: Your bio is f**cking awesome!

Answer (score 0):

You have to make a php server. Free MAC php/ mysql server http://www.mamp.info/en/index.html